# How to compute the gradient and hessian of logarithmic loss? (question is based on a numpy example script from xgboost's github repository)

Tags: entropy, loss-functions, derivative, gradient, boosting

I would like to understand how the gradient and hessian of the logloss function are computed in an [xgboost sample script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dmlc/xgboost/master/demo/guide-python/custom_objective.py).

I've simplified the function to take numpy arrays, and generated `y_hat` and `y_true` which are a sample of the values used in the script.

Here is the simplified example:

```
import numpy as np


def loglikelihoodloss(y_hat, y_true):
    prob = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-y_hat))
    grad = prob - y_true
    hess = prob * (1.0 - prob)
    return grad, hess

y_hat = np.array([1.80087972, -1.82414818, -1.82414818,  1.80087972, -2.08465433,
                  -1.82414818, -1.82414818,  1.80087972, -1.82414818, -1.82414818])
y_true = np.array([1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.])

loglikelihoodloss(y_hat, y_true)
```

The log loss function is the sum of $y\ln\left(p\right)+\left(1-y\right)\ln\left(1-p\right)$ where $p = \dfrac{1}{(1 + e^{-x})}$.

The gradient (with respect to p) is then $\dfrac{p-y}{\left(p-1\right)p}$ however in the code its $p -y$.

Likewise the second derivative (with respect to p) is
$\dfrac{\left(y-p\right)p+y\left(p-1\right)}{\left(p-1\right)^2p^2}$ however in the code it is $p(1-p)$.

How are the equations equal?

Comment: what is x in e^(-x)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The derivatives are with respect to $x$ (or `y_hat` in the code) instead of $p$.

As you've already derived 
(**Edit:** as Simon.H mentioned, since the actual loss should be the **negative** log likelihood, so I've changed the sign of your result)
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=\frac{p-y}{\left(1-p\right)p},$$
and [the derivative of sigmoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/78575/291503) is
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=p(1-p),$$
so
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=p-y,$$
and the second order derivative
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(p-y)=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=p(1-p).$$